# Can't prevent clearing of selected option after "onClick" executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am currently working on a page that sends data via ajax and uses the response to reset the controls in the form.

When the button's `onClick` function is called it all works well but the value I select in my list gets unselected.

I stepped through the code and I can see that the selected option stays selected until the step after the function returns. When the last step runs something happens which causes my option to become unselected.

Here is the code I am using:

HTML:

```
<button id="update" name="update" value="update" onclick="updateStudent(this, 'Student')">Update Student</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function updateStudent(obj, theTitle){
    
    var SID = sendForm(obj, theTitle); //ajax update.
    
    // Select Student just updated
    $('#sid option[value=' + SID + ']').prop('selected', 'true');
    $('#sid').click(); // Trigger select's OnClick method
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to return something from the ajax request to `SID`? If so, it won't work, as ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: I am returning something and I'm running ajax with "async: false"

Comment: And are you sure it's returning what you expect? Set a breakpoint or console.log to confirm.

Comment: Yes. I can step through it and it everything works fine. My problem is that after it returns from the function called by the button instead of just ending execution and leaving the page as I set it, it seems to refresh it and every field retains the values I set them to except for the select.

Comment: It's not the problem, but your `.prop('selected', 'true');` shouldn't have quotes around `true`, e.g.: `.prop('selected', true);`. And unless it's a multi-select, you should use `val` on the `select` box itself instead of `selected` on the `option`. (If it *is* a multi-select, though, obviously not.)

Answer (score 0):

The `button` element is, by default, a **submit** button. If you add

```
type="button"
```

...to it, e.g.:

```
<button id="update" type="button" name="update" value="update" onclick="updateStudent(this, 'Student')">Update Student</button>
<!-- New bit -------^^^^^^^^^^^^^         -->
```

...that will prevent it from submitting the form and rewriting the entire page.

Comment: I have a function that overwrites the submit `$(form[0]).submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault() })` I added the `type="button"` but it still rewrites the page (though all the other fields in the form retain the values I set them to except for the select.)

Comment: @ElCas: Then you'll have to provide a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem, the question doesn't have enough information in it to help you. If you're really cancelling the form submit, the page shouldn't refresh, which suggests the problem is in the code cancelling the submit. It works here, for instance: http://jsbin.com/uwewan/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/uwewan/1/edit).

Comment: @ T.J.Crowder I created a test using my exact code and simulating the ajax calls and it worked correctly [link](http://jsbin.com/uwewan/6). I guess I'll have to see continue going through the code and see if I can find the cause for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**AJAX is asynchronous**

You need to set that in the success callback.

Comment: I have my code that sets all the form fields in the success callback function.